# Write the solution as a Fourier Series. $u_{tt}=u_{xx},~ u(t,0)=u(t,\pi)=0,~u(0,x)=1, u_t(0,x)=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm running into a roadblock on this IBV problem

$$u_{tt}=u_{xx},~ u(t,0)=u(t,\pi)=0,~u(0,x)=1, u_t(0,x)=0$$

Assuming separability:

$$u(t,x)=w(t)v(x) \implies  w^{\prime\prime}(t)=\lambda w(t)~~\mbox{and}~~v^{\prime\prime}(x)=\lambda v(x)$$

1. If $\lambda=-\omega^2<0$ then
   \begin{align} 
   w(t) &= \sin(\omega t) \ \mbox{or} \ w(t) = \cos(\omega t) \\ v(x) &= \sin(\omega x) \ \mbox{or} \ v(x) = \cos(\omega x)
   \end{align}
2. If $\lambda=0$ then
   \begin{align}
   w(t) &= 1 \ \mbox{or} \ w(t) = t \\
   v(x) &= 1 \ \mbox{or} \ v(x) = x
   \end{align}
3. If $\lambda=\omega^2$ then
   \begin{align}
   w(t) &= e^{-\omega t} \ \mbox{or} \ w(t) = e^{\omega t} \\ 
   v(x) &= e^{-\omega x} \ \mbox{or} \ v(x) = e^{\omega x}
   \end{align}

By initial boundary condition $u(t,0) = u(t,\pi) = 0$, we have $v(0) = v(\pi) = 0 \implies v(x) = \sin(\omega x)$.

Here's where I encounter my roadblock. By the IC $u(0,x)=1$, we have $w(0)=\frac{1}{v(x)}$ (which is not a possible solution for $w(t)$. Am I to conclude in this scenario that the function $u(t,x)$ is not separable and I must seek another strategy for finding the solution?

**Further Analysis:**
Based on $v(x)=\sin(\omega x)$ in conjunction with $u(0,x)=1\implies \sin(\omega x)=1$ at $w(0)=1$.  Thus, $\omega=n\pi$ and $w_n(t)=\cos(n\pi t)$ and therefore $$u_n(t,x)=\cos(n\pi t)\sin(n\pi x)~~~n=1,2,3,...$$

I think I may have solved my own problem.  If I'm making an error here, please correct me.

This brings me to a new stumbling block.  Translating this solution into a Fourier Series solution:

Logically (in my mind at least) $u(t,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n(t,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n \cos{(nt)}\sin(nx)$

Solving for $b_n$ is a little tricky for me here.  I'm using v(x) to find the $b_n$ values in the following integral.  I don't see how to put the result back into the Fourier Sum.

$$b_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi{\sin(\omega x)\sin(kx)}=2~~~\forall ~\omega=k$$

**End Further Analysis**

This problem is from Chapter 4.2 of "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations" by Peter Olver.  The section is on Separation of Variables, hence the approach I am trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

- $\ds{u\pars{x,t} =
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\pars{t}\sin\pars{nx}}$ satisfies
  $\ds{u\pars{t,0} = u\pars{t,\pi} = 0\,\ \forall t}$.
- $\ds{
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{\ddot{a}_{n} + n^{2}a_{n}\pars{t}}\sin\pars{nx} = 0 \implies
  \ddot{a}_{n} + n^{2}a_{n}\pars{t} = 0}$.
- $\ds{
  a_{n}\pars{t} = b_{n}\sin\pars{nt} + c_{n}\cos\pars{nt}}$
- $\ds{u\pars{x,t} =
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{b_{n}\sin\pars{nt} + c_{n}\cos\pars{nt}}\sin\pars{nx}}$
- $\ds{0 =
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}b_{n}n\sin\pars{nx} \implies b_{n} = 0}$
- $\ds{u\pars{x,t} =
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}c_{n}\cos\pars{nt}\sin\pars{nx}}$
- $\ds{1 =
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}c_{n}\sin\pars{nx}}$:
  \begin{align}
  &\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\pars{nx}\dd x}
  ^{\ds{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over n}}\ =\
  \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}c_{m}\
  \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\pars{nx}\sin\pars{mx}\dd x}^{\ds{{\pi \over 2}\delta_{nm}}}
  \\[5mm] &\
  \implies c_{n} = {2 \over \pi}\,
  {1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over n}
  \end{align}
- $\ds{\bbx{u\pars{t,x} =
  {4 \over \pi}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
  {\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}t}\sin\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}x} \over 2n + 1}}}$

Comment: @C-Web Thanks.$\mbox{}$

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bit of confusion in your working, so I will outline a general approach to solve the problem. You have assumed separability and determined ODEs correctly. Next, you need to solve the ODEs (as you have done, but with some caveats). The general solution to

$$v'' = -\omega^{2} v$$

is

$$v = A \cos(\omega x) + B \sin(\omega x)$$

You can't say *apriori* it is $\cos(\omega x)$ or $\sin(\omega x)$; it could also be a sum of both (which is what you get when you have periodic boundary conditions). The boundary conditions determine the particular eigenfunction(s). Applying the boundary condition $v(0) = 0 \implies A = 0$. Applying the other boundary condition $v(\pi) = B \sin(\omega \pi) = 0$, we see that if $B = 0$ we get the trivial solution. Hence, we assume $B \ne 0$ and so $\sin(\omega \pi) = 0 \implies \omega = n, \ n \ge 1$ and so the spatial eigenfunction and eigenvalue are determined to be $v = B_{n} \sin(n x)$ and $\lambda = -n^{2}$. Going to the ODE in $t$, you need to solve

$$w'' = -n^{2}w$$

which has solution

$$w = C_{n} \cos(nt) + D_{n} \sin(nt)$$

The general solution is then a superposition

$$u = \sum_{n \ge 1} [C_{n} \cos(nt) + D_{n} \sin(nt)] \sin(nx)$$

which you can check satisfies the original PDE. It is at this point that you apply the ICs. You have

$$u(0,x) = 1 = \sum_{n \ge 1} C_{n} \sin(nx)$$

To determine the coefficients $C_{n}$, multiply both sides by $\sin(mx)$ and integrating over the domain $x \in [0, \pi]$

$$\implies \int_{0}^{\pi} 1 \cdot \sin(mx) dx = \sum_{n \ge 1} C_{n} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(nx) \sin(mx) dx$$

which yields the [orthogonality relations](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Elaugesen/285/orthogonality.pdf). Once you have determined $C_{n}$ explicitly, you can use the same approach to determine $D_{n}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has been very helpful.  I'm running into another stumbling block if you don't mind explaining further.  I found $C_n=\frac{2}{n\pi}$ if $n$ is odd and $n=m$.  How do I reconcile the $n=m$ back into the problem?

Comment: I came up with $u=\frac{2}{\pi m}\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos((2n-1)t)\sin((2n-1)x)~~\forall~m=2n-1$ I feel like I'm still missing something along the way here.  I feel like I should be getting a more concrete result that is not dependent on $m$.

Comment: @C-Web Sorry, I'm not quite following. You have shown $m = 2n - 1$, so the $2/(m \pi)$ term should be contained in the summation, to yield the solution $$u = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{\cos((2n - 1)t) \sin((2n-1)x)}{2n-1}$$ Just check to make sure your coefficient is correct, comparing with Felix's solution above you are missing a factor of $2$.

Comment: I get a little twisted up in my thinking connecting the m and the n when solving for the coefficients kinda throws me off.  As for the factor of 2, I initially did not take into account that I was taking the integral only on half of the $2\pi$ period, thus had to reduce the solution by half.

Answer (score 0):

With $v(x)=A\cos(\omega x)+B\sin(\omega x)$ and
$u(t,0)=u(t,\pi)=0\implies v(0)=v(\pi)=0\implies A=0~$ and $v(x)=B\sin(\omega x)$ and $$v_n(x)=B_n\sin(nx)~~\mbox{with}~~~\lambda=-n^2$$

Similarly, $$w_n(t)=C_n\cos(nt)+D_n\sin(nt)$$
$$u=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[C_n\cos(nt)\sin(nx)+D_n\sin(nt)\sin(nx)]$$
IC $u(0,x)=1\implies u=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[C_n\cos(0)\sin(nx)+D_n\sin(0)\sin(nx)]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\sin(nx)=1$
$$C_m=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi{1\cdot\sin(mx)dx}= \frac{2}{\pi}\left[\frac{-1}{m}cos(m\pi)+\frac{1}{m}cos(0)\right]=\frac{4}{m\pi}$$

$w^\prime=\frac{-C}{\omega}\sin(\omega t)+\frac{D}{\omega}\cos(\omega t)$ and

$u_{t_n}=\left[\frac{-C_n}{n}\sin(nt)+\frac{D_n}{n}\cos(nt)\right]\sin(nx)$.  With IC $u_t(0,x)=0$ $$\implies u_t(0,x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{-C_n}{n}\sin(0)+\frac{D_n}{n}\cos(0)\right]\sin(nx)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{D_n}{n}\sin(nx)=0$$ $$\implies D_n=0$$
Thus, $$u(t,x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos((2n-1)t)\sin((2n-1)x)}{(2n-1)}$$